# Microsoft graph API how to create a bearer msal token

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Trying to authenticate, as an application from a basic console app, (not as a user) and get an access token with the right scopes. I manage to get a token but without the right scopes. I'm not sure if you even are able to do like this, what am I missing?

```
static async Task<string> GetMsalToken()
        {
            const string clientId = "xxxx234a3-7b9f-42341c-86df-3d2349861";
            const string clientSecret = "WX324XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            var scopes = new List<string>() { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var clientCredential = new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientCredential(clientSecret);
            var redirecturi = "msalxxxx234a3-7b9f-42341c-86df-3d2349861://auth";

            var clientApplication = new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication(clientId, redirecturi, clientCredential, null, null);
            var authenticationResult = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);

            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
```

Comment: What scopes are you getting and what scopes do you want?

Comment: Currently I'm not getting any scopes at all, and from what I understand .default is use to get scopes defined in the app registration portal, or am I wrong!? There I defind several scopes, User.Read.All e.g

Comment: Why don't you try passing in the scopes directly into the "scopes" variable?

Comment: When I do that I get an exception saying I'm passing in unknown scopes!? Only variable that is working is .default!?

Comment: You should share exactly what you are passing to get that error.

Comment: Sorry, I will do that the first thing I do when I get back to my code/office on monday morning. Thanks!

Comment: Passing in "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All" or "User.Read.All" to the scopes array this error gets generated:

Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All is not valid.
Trace ID: 15a8c097-a5f9-4012-833b-62787d654e00
Correlation ID: 24766b01-b476-492e-974c-ad995a801f8e

Comment: Where is the "https://"?

Comment: It's treated as a link, if you copy it the https will be there

Comment: Try to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default ` and do admin consent . If you don't perform the admin consent , the access token will not have any application permission .

Comment: Nan, thanks for the comment, I tried that one as well but still there are no scopes being set.

Comment: Please confirm 1. you have set `application permissions` in app registration portal .2 . perform the admin consent . Please check [this document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/) for more details .

Comment: Yes, both steps have been done, and it's seems to working correctly, being redirected when implementing it in a web application, BUT still no scopes..

Answer (score 2):

You are using client credential authentication using application permissions in Azure AD V2.0 endpoint , the value passed for the scope parameter in this request should be the resource identifier (Application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix. For example ,the Microsoft Graph , the value is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default.

With client credential flow , the application uses the all organization's data, not for the specific user. In such a case, the "administrator consent" (admin consent) is used in Azure AD, and this consent must be done by the administrator in the organization. When you use the administrator consent, all you have to do is to go to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant name}/adminconsent?client_id={application id}&state={some state data}&redirect_uri={redirect uri}`using web browser.

After admin consent , acquiring token for microsoft graph using client credential flow , if you decode your access token using [online tool](https://jwt.io/) , you could find application permissions are listed in `roles` claim . Please confirm you have done the admin consent for application permissions .

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/) is is a tutorial for using client credentials flow with Azure AD V2.0 endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Nan, it finally worked, I basically followed the link..

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/

Comment: So which factor cause your issue , and if the reply helps ,please consider accept as answer , which may help others who meet same problem .